# Can see variable defined inside method from unit test

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am running unit test in angular, I can test if the method is called or not also see if the variable initialized inside this method is defined or not.For both of this test passes. Please let me know when the method is called, it must define the variable inside it also

**spec.ts**

```
let spyDate = spyOn(component, "setDateFilter");
component.setDateFilter('2019', '2', '13', '2019', '3', '11');
expect(spyDate).toHaveBeenCalled();//passes
expect(component.filter.from).toBeDefined();//passes,but
console.log(component.filter.from);// is just ' ',I expect 2019-03-11T23:00:00.000Z
```

```
filter={
from:'',
to:''
}
```

**component.ts**

```
setDateFilter(yearX, monthX, dayX, yearY, monthY, dayY) {
  console.log(monthX + '  ' + monthY);
  //+''+ monthX+'' +dayX+''+ yearY+''+monthY+''+dayY );
  this.filter.from = (new Date(yearX, monthX, dayX, 0, 0, 0)).toISOString();
  this.filter.to = (new Date(yearY, monthY, dayY, 23, 59, 59)).toISOString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use andCallThrough() after calling spyOn().That way the spy will pass any calls to it through to the original function.

```
let spyDate=spyOn(component,"setDateFilter").andCallThrough();
```

Comment: superb it works!!! Thanks Iulian Cucoanis just one correction it is and.callThrough();

Comment: Ooops! Forgot it was changed to .and.callThrough(). Glad I could help!